# How do I make Html.TextBoxFor DateTime accept user input of dd.MM.yy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to make a page where the user can search for articles. There is an option to limit the search based on a `FromDate` and a `ToDate`. Both of these are `DateTime`.

The user is asked to enter the date on the form `dd.MM.yy`as this is normal in our country. I can see the date in the URL after submitting the form and it looks as I want it to. The problem however is that MVC3 assumes the format is `MM.dd.yy`. How can I change this?

Some code:
This is the Razor code I use

```
<div class="toDate" >
  <label>til dato</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTo, new { placeholder = "dd.mm.yy" })
</div>
```

And in the model all I have is:

```
public DateTime DateTo { set; get; }
```

I have tried using EditorFor, but I lose my placeholder text.

**In short: How do I make my MVC3 model accept a DateTime input from the user on the form dd.MM.yy**

If my question isn't clear enough, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

EDIT:
It appears that I need some clarification, so I'll try to do that by making a scenario:

1. The user enters his search criteria. He sets a DateFrom and a DateTo in two text boxes.
2. The form is submitted and posted back to the server.
3. On the server the DateTime object is treated on the form MM.dd.yy. I wish for it to be interpreted as dd.MM.yy.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MM yy}")]
pubilc DateTime DateTo { get; set }
```

Comment: Vill this really validate the input according to a specific format as well?

Comment: ye really it will work ,You just need to add this lines in the model class

Comment: I can't make this work. It seems as if this is used if I set the value of the TextBox? What I'm trying to do is to take the user's input and use it in a search - I want my model to accept that input on the form dd.Mm.yy. (I have also tried your example with {0:dd.MM.yy})

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a custom validation attribute where you validate the date format according to your liking.

Here's a nice tutorial for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618485 (It's not as difficulty as it might seem at first, and can be really helpful).

Alternatively just build a regex validation attribute with something like:

```
RegularExpression(@"[0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9].[0-9][0-9]")]
```

Above regex isn't perfect, but serves as an example.

Edit: If **3nigma**'s solution works for you that is obviously highly preferable to mine. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not trying to validate the user's input. I'm trying to make my model accept it on the form dd.MM.yy. Even a correct input on that form is treated as MM.dd.yy.

Comment: I think I'm having a problem understanding the problem here - even after reading your comments on the other answer here. Can you try to elaborate with some more examples in your original post?

Comment: I added some clarification to my original post. Hope that helps.